# Escriba una función que reciba un diccionario [código del estudiante, nombres, apellidos, documento, programa, promedio ponderado, correo U]

Tags: python

seleccion = dict()
seleccion = {
20170136837:{'nombres':'Jorge Juan','apellido':'Moreno , López','documento':88481595,'programa':'ARQU','materia':
{'facultad': 'Arquitetura','codigo':'ARQU-2113','nota': 2.97,'creditos': 2 ,'retirada':'Si',
'facultad':'Arquitetura','codigo':'ARQU-5048','nota':4.26,'creditos':0,'retirada':'No'} },

20130225137:{'nombres':'Sara Carolina','apellido':'Gómez,Fernández','documento': 58770043,'programa':'ARQD','materia':
{'facultad': 'Arquitetura','codigo':'ARQU-2113','nota': 3.36,'creditos': 3,
'retirada':'No','facultad': 'Arquitetura','codigo':'ARQU-2113','nota': 1.59,'creditos':4,'retirada':'Si'} } }

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Nos diste un enunciado y unos datos, como esperando que alguien haga el código por tí. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!